# OTS parsing error, Failed to decode downloaded font: <URL>, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected '<'

Tags: css, reactjs, angular, iframe, fonts

Greeting,
I have the following situation: In the Angular.js app using Iframe[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk1NQ.png) I load the React app. The fonts are in the React app and were loaded properly while the path looked like this: '/ example', when I created the nested route '/example/something' the fonts are still loading correctly but a warning appeared:

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk1NQ.png this is link, I made mistake.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.